# How do I grep the list of results and print them with serial number?

Tags: grep, sqoop

I used a command in Sqoop to list the tables in my SQL Server that start with 'lkp' in table names

```
$sqoop list-tables | grep -i 'lkp'
```

What I need is I want to list the 'lkp' tables with serial numbers so I tried with the command

```
$sqoop list-tables | grep -in 'lkp'
```

but it resulted with numbers of entire list of tables irrespective of name 'lkp' as

> 7:LKP_AttributeType
>
> 11:LKP_CalendarName
>
> 22.LKP_CategoryError
>
> 27:LKP_ColumnDataType
>
> 38:LKP_ColumnName
>
> and so on....

what I need is

> 1:LKP_AttributeType
>
> 2:LKP_CalendarName
>
> 3.LKP_CategoryError
>
> 4:LKP_ColumnDataType
>
> 5:LKP_ColumnName

Can any one explain me how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with sqoop, but can you use the "nl" command line tool to add line numbers to the grep output?

```
$sqoop list-tables | grep -i 'lkp' | nl
```

Comment: Thanks it worked !!! Actually its not related to sqoop, it could be anything just like **ls** which simply lists the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this command line

```
sqoop list-tables | grep -i 'lkp'| awk '{print NR,$0}'
```

Comment: Thanks Michael Cresta ! This is indeed faster.